# Localize API Response in addition to return the value itself

Tags: node.js, api, localization, internationalization

I'm working on a new project which supports 3 languages, I'm using Node.js and I want to localize some properties in API response in addition to return the original value, for example:

I'm working on the admins list and every admin has gender saved in the database as an enum, the super admin can edit another admin so when I fetch the admin details I will need to get the gender ( male ) in edit view in addition to localized gender (Male) so I can display it in the show view.

The question is, which one of those approaches is the best?

1- return both gender and localized gender in an object called gender with id and localized title?

```
"gender": {
    "id": "male",
    "localized": "Male",
}
```

2- return 2 priorities in the admin object for the localized gender and the gender value?

```
"gender": "male",
"gender_localized": "Male",
```

or maybe something else better than those approaches?
The gender in admins is a very simple example.

Comment: Have you considered doing localization on the client-side? Might make more sense and be simpler. If you prefer to keep it server-side, I'd go with the 1st option, as I like using "namespaces" when using dictionaries. Makes unpacking and other processing operations simpler.

Comment: I thought in it but in case I have mobile apps and 2 web apps it will duplicate the work also the localization maybe different from client to another, also after I search on the web many developers said the localization should be on the server side.